# Identity key counter increment by one although it is in TRY Catch and Transaction is roll-backed ? SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Identity counter increment by one although it is in TRY Catch and Transaction is roll-backed ? SSMS 2008 is there any way i can stop it +1 or rollback it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand why this happened, Let's execute below sample code first-

```
USE tempdb

CREATE  TABLE dbo.Sales
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Address VARCHAR(200))
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT DBO.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Now, Execution plan for above query is-
[image]

The second last operator from right `Compute Scalar` is computing value for `[Expr1003]=getidentity((629577281),(2),NULL)` which is IDENTITY value for ID column. So this clearly indicates that IDENTITY values are fetched & Incremented prior to Insertion (`INSERT Operator`). So its by nature that even transaction rollback at later stage once created IDENTITY value is there.

Now, in order to reseed the IDENTITY value to Maximum Identity Value present in table + 1, you need sysadmin permission to execute below DBCC command -

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT   
 (   
    table_name  
        [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ]  
)  
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

So the final query should include below piece of code prior to rollback statement:-

```
--  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales')
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'dbo.Sales', RESEED, @MaxValue ) 

--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

So it is recommended to leave it on SQL Server.

Comment: what if we have 3 insert query and Successor insert uses predecessor's auto id   @ajaydwivedi  how to reset the auto ID!!

Comment: Hi @ManojKargeti, Let's understand this using [AdventureWorks2016] database. We generate `SalesOrderID` in table `sales.SalesOrderHeader`, and use the generated ID in subsequent child tables like `sales.SalesOrderDetail`. When rollback is needed, since data population in child tables is not using IDENTITY field of its own, rather generated IDENTITY of `sales.SalesOrderHeader`, we only need to RESEED Identity for table `sales.SalesOrderHeader`.

Comment: Hi @ajaydwivedi, let say my insert query fails in try block at 3rd insertion and i want to rollback all auto ids  generated  in all table with rollback .How can i implement . what i am doing now is DECLARE MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
IF MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales')
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'dbo.Sales', RESEED, MaxValue )

Comment: 3 times (and with obvious different variable) but it does not reseeding the identity value if run in catch block .

Comment: I am testing executing by exec <spname> but id do not reseeding the identity value , but when i run query separate  it works ..!! any soution .i am RESEED it before rollback !! is it correct way..

Comment: I am testing executing by exec <spname> but id do not reseeding the identity value , but when i run query separate it works ..!! any soution .i am RESEED it before rollback !! is it correct way @ajaydwivedi

Comment: @ManojKargeti, I don't think there is any straight solution for multi-identity inserts within one transaction. Yes, post transaction (after ROLLBACK), you can attach a piece of code for each affected table to verify if max value of ID column is equal to IDENTITY value returned by `IDENT_CURRENT()`, and RESEED each table based on it.

Comment: It's executing successfully in my case. Below is the query.

`BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT DBO.Sales
            ( Address )
    VALUES  ( 'Dwarka, Delhi' );

 DELETE FROM DBO.Sales;

 --  Code to check max ID value, and verify it again IDENTITY SEED
 DECLARE @MaxValue INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),1) FROM dbo.Sales)
 IF @MaxValue IS NOT NULL AND @MaxValue <> IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Sales')
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'dbo.Sales', RESEED, @MaxValue );
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Comment: @ManojKargeti, Sorry I missed, you are using procedure name to execute. I only know that its permission issue with procedure. By default, procedure executes under the access rights of user in context (one who is executing procedure). But I'll surely get back to you on this.

Comment: thanks that works for me but now if no row affected then also it taking as a valid case ?? how to prevent it @ajaydwivedi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125603/discussion-between-ajay-dwivedi-and-manoj-kargeti).

Answer (score 1):

You are right and the following code inserts record with `[Col01]` equal to `2`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [Col01] SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Col02] TINYINT
);

GO

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col02])
    VALUES (1);

    SELECT 1/0

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;

END CATCH;

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col02])
VALUES (1);

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource]
```

This is by design (as you can see in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx):

> Consecutive values after server restart or other failures –SQL Server
>   might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the
>   assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>   restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If
>   gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own
>   mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the
>   NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never
>   committed.

I try using `NOCACHE` sequence but it does not work on `SQL Server 2012`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [Col01] SMALLINT 
   ,[Col02] TINYINT
);

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MyIndentyty]
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    NO CACHE;  
GO  


BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col01], [Col02])
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[MyIndentyty], 1

    SELECT 1/0

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;

END CATCH;

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col01], [Col02])
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[MyIndentyty], 1

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource]

DROP TABLE [dbo].[DataSource];
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[MyIndentyty];
```

You can use `MAX` to solve this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [Col01] SMALLINT 
   ,[Col02] TINYINT
);


BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @Value SMALLINT = (SELECT MAX([Col01]) FROM [dbo].[DataSource]);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col01], [Col02])
    SELECT @Value, 1

    SELECT 1/0

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;

END CATCH;

GO

DECLARE @Value SMALLINT = ISNULL((SELECT MAX([Col01]) FROM [dbo].[DataSource]), 1);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([Col01], [Col02])
SELECT @Value, 1

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource]

DROP TABLE [dbo].[DataSource];
```

But you must pay attentions to your [isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149(v=sql.110).aspx) for potential issues:

[image]

If you want to insert many rows at the same time, do the following:

1. get the current max value
2. create table where to store the rows (that are going to be inserted) generating ranking (you can use identity column, you can use ranking function) and adding the max value to it
3. insert the rows

Comment: @[User::VarLogFolderPath]+"\\"+ @[System::PackageName]+"_"+Replace(Replace(Replace(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)(GETDATE()),1,16),"-","")," ","_"),":","")+".log"